# purpose of (array) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I came across `(array)` in WordPress in the following code but looked in the PHP manual search for (array) but could not find anything (https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=%28array%29&scope=quickref)

```
foreach ( (array) $cron as $timestamp => $hooks) {
    foreach ( (array) $hooks as $hook => $args ) {
        $key = md5(serialize($args['args']));
        $new_cron[$timestamp][$hook][$key] = $args;
    }
}
```

Could someone please explain what this `(array)` does?

Comment: Hello, you haven't actually accepted an answer for this question yet. I wonder if you would mind selecting my answer, if it helped you?
Thanks, have a great day!

Comment: Yes, your answer helped me, but it's not a sufficient correct answer.  In it's current form, it claims that perhaps type-casting can change an object into an array, which it can't under any circumstances.

Comment: Righto. You could have commented that when I asked you if I could improve my answer on June 7, but sure - do you.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond.  To be honest, I wasn't sure whether the answers were correct and didn't want to mark them as correct until I was sure.  @Marcos answer was posted before yours, so I gave him the correct answer since it answered the question succinctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called casting a variable (AKA casting or type-juggling). You are saying you want $cronhooks to be converted to and evaluated as an array. Look at this example:

```
$a = (int) 5.3;
print($a);
5
```

The (int) indicates that I want an integer from 5.3. so the PHP convert it.

Answer (score 1):

It's casting the variable to an array. Perhaps $cronhooks was an object rather than an array, and could not be iterated as a key => value array.

Here's the manual page for Type Jugling in PHP
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Array members can be accessed using index or key as follow:

```php
$cronhooks[0];     // the first member
$people['tom'];    // the member with the key 'tom'
```

objects and classes have members which are accessed using the object operator:

```php
$person->name;    // name property of a person object
$person->save();  // might be a method to save the person back to the database
```

Interestingly wordpress has a built in internal function called `_get_cron_array()` which should return the cron jobs as an array.

Currently that source code is here:
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/056b9c47a2114a23e9a892df2d5f79856dbe5a73/wp-includes/cron.php#L924-L945

But even in their own code they are casting it to array, which seems odd given the function professes to return an array in it's name!

That one casting example:
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/056b9c47a2114a23e9a892df2d5f79856dbe5a73/wp-includes/cron.php#L95

Anyway this was fun to explore :D

Comment: The manual mentions that "Note that this does not change the types of the operands themselves; the only change is in how the operands are evaluated and what the type of the expression itself is.".  Would using (array) on a class not be changing the type of the operand itself?

Comment: @jonnyjandles interesting question - I think that applies more to when PHP is automatically type juggling for you, particularly with mathematical operations.  I always assumed once an object is cast to an array it loses it's memory of ever having been an object.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I noticed the same thing that _get_cron_array() was returning an array and tried to add that in the OP. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Anything else I can do to make this a complete answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is infact known as type-juggling, or type-casting.

In some cases (such as int to float, int to string, string to an array, int to an array) the type will be converted (allowing a regular string or int to be looped though as in the example above).

However, some types cannot be effectively converted to another, such as an array to a string, int, or class object for some examples and PHP will issue a notice such as:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /path/file.php on line 10
```

and the array will be converted to a string with the contents "Array".  However your PHP will not throw an error so the script will continue and not work as you probably expected.